# Remove adjacent Duplicates from a String which have count greater than or equal to burst Length

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, data-structures, stack

Given a string with repeating characters and a burst length, output the string such that the count of the same adjacent characters in the string is less than the burst length.

Input : abbccccdd, burstLen  = 3

Correct Output : abbdd
My Output: abbd

Input : abbcccdeaffff, burstLen =  3

Correct Output: abbdea

 My Output: abbea

```
//Radhe krishna ki jytoi alokik
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

string solve(string s, int burstLen)
{
    stack<pair<char, int>> ms;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!ms.empty() && ms.top().first == s[i])
        {
            int count = ms.top().second;
            ms.push({s[i], count + 1});
        }
        
        else
        {
            if(ms.empty() == true  ||  ms.top().first != s[i])
            {
                if(!ms.empty() && ms.top().second >= burstLen)
                {
                    int count = ms.top().second;
                    
                    while(!ms.empty() && count--)
                        ms.pop();
                    //(UPDATE)
                     ms.push({s[i], 1});
                }
                
                else
                    ms.push({s[i], 1});
            }
        }

    }
    
    if(!ms.empty() and ms.top().second >= burstLen)
    {
        int count = ms.top().second;
        while(!ms.empty() && count--)
            ms.pop();
    }

    string ans = "";
    while (!ms.empty())
    {
        ans += ms.top().first;
        ms.pop();
    }
    
    reverse(ans.begin(), ans.end());    
    return ans;
}


int main()
{


    
        string s;
        int burstLen;

        cin >> s;
        cin >> burstLen;

        cout << solve(s, burstLen) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Careful with `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;`. They can wreck a program in only a few lines.

Comment: I think you're over-complicating. As you're scanning the string you could count the number of times you've seen the current character. When you see a new character  you add the character to an output string if the count is less than the burst length, reset the counter and start processing the new character.

Comment: Your question appears to be missing the question part.  Are you looking for a code review?

Comment: what is your question? Does your code not do what you want? Do you get compiler errors? Please include them in the question. Wrong output? Please include input, output and expected output in the question

Comment: Yeah, Kind of, I tried it using pen and paper but somewhere i am missing some condition,  yeah need help in fixing this.

Comment: @idclev463035818  I have updated input , expect output and my output in the question, Please Check

Comment: yeah sorry, it was there already before....

Comment: @Eljay Fixed, Yeah I am missing some conditions and tried a couple of times , but not able to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better at least to use the container adapter `std::queue` instead of `std::stack` because  there would not be a need to call the algorithm `std::reverse`.

Moreover if items of the stack contain the second data member that stores frequencies then you could just increase this data member for repeated characters instead of placing each repeated character in the stack.

For example this code snippet in your program

```
    if (!ms.empty() && ms.top().first == s[i])
    {
        int count = ms.top().second;
        ms.push({s[i], count + 1});
    }
```

makes the function definition too complicated and unclear because the same character is pushed on the stack with different frequencies.

Nevertheless if you want to use the container adapter std::stack the function definition could look simpler. You are not using features of the class `std::string`.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function could be written using your approach with `std::stack`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <stack>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::string solve( const std::string &s, size_t burstLen )
{
    std::stack<std::pair<char, size_t>> stack;
    
    for ( const auto &c : s )
    {
        if ( stack.empty() || stack.top().first != c )
        {
            stack.push( { c, 1 } );
        }
        else
        {
            ++stack.top().second;
        }
    }

    std::string ans;
    
    while ( !stack.empty() )
    {
        if ( stack.top().second < burstLen )
        {
            ans.append( stack.top().second, stack.top().first );
        }
        stack.pop();
    }
    
    std::reverse( std::begin( ans ), std::end( ans ) );
    
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << solve( "abbccccdd", 3 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << solve( "abbcccdeaffff", 3 ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
abbdd
abbdea
```

It is interesting to use the stack when after removing a sequence of characters that is not less than the burst length you get from the left and right side sub-sequences anew sequence that again is not less than burst length and you need also to remove it.

In this case you can use two stacks.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <stack>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::string solve( const std::string &s, size_t burstLen )
{
    std::stack<std::pair<char, size_t>> stack_in;
    
    for ( const auto &c : s )
    {
        if ( stack_in.empty() || stack_in.top().first != c )
        {
            stack_in.push( { c, 1 } );
        }
        else
        {
            ++stack_in.top().second;
        }
    }

    std::stack<std::pair<char, size_t>> stack_out;

    while ( !stack_in.empty() )
    {
        if ( !stack_out.empty() && stack_out.top().first == stack_in.top().first )
        {
            if ( stack_out.top().second + stack_in.top().second < burstLen )
            {
                stack_out.top().second += stack_in.top().second;
            }
            else
            {
                stack_out.pop();
            }
        }
        else if ( stack_in.top().second < burstLen )
        {
            stack_out.push( stack_in.top() );
        }
        
        stack_in.pop();
    }
    
    std::string ans;
    
    while ( !stack_out.empty() )
    {
        ans.append( stack_out.top().second, stack_out.top().first );
        stack_out.pop();
    }
    
    return ans;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << solve( "abbccccdd", 3 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << solve( "abbcccdeaffff", 3 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << solve( "aabcddeeedccbaa", 3 );
}
```

The program output is

```
abbdd
abbdea
aabbaa
```

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a try but it looks complicated so I suggest making a simpler function using a few functions from the standard library.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iterator>

std::string solve(const std::string& in, size_t burstlen) {
    std::string retval;

    for(std::string::const_iterator begin = in.cbegin(), bend;
        begin != in.end();
        begin = bend) 
    {

        // find the first char not equal to the current char
        bend = std::find_if_not(std::next(begin), in.end(), 
                                [curr=*begin](char ch){ return ch==curr; });

        if(std::distance(begin, bend) < burstlen) {
            // length ok, append it
            retval.append(begin, bend);
        }
    }

    return retval;
}

int main() {
    std::initializer_list<std::string> tests{
        "abbccccdd", "abbcccdeaffff"};
    for(auto test : tests) std::cout << solve(test, 3) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
abbdd
abbdea
```

Answer (score 0):

My Approach to the Solution :

Create a Stack of pair which consists of character and character count

If the Stack is empty or the top element of the stack is not equal to the current element in the string

Case 1: if the frequency of the top element of the stack is greater than or equal to k, store it in a variable say count, Pop the element of Stack count times.

Case 2: if the Stack is Empty, then simply push the element in stack with frequency 1.

Upon Traversing the complete string, if the top element of the stack is having a frequency greater than bursten, start removing elements from the stack (count) number of times.

Now, we have leftout elements in the stack, Start popping them and store them in a string and reverse the string to preserve the order.

Return the new string.

UPDATE : SOLVED. Missing one line in this condition if(ms.empty() == true || ms.top().first != s[i]) After popping the elements, We also have to insert the present element with character frequency 1.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;

string solve(string s, int burstLen)
{
    stack<pair<char, int>> ms;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!ms.empty() && ms.top().first == s[i])
        {
            int count = ms.top().second;
            ms.push({s[i], count + 1});
        }
        
        else
        {
            if(ms.empty() == true  ||  ms.top().first != s[i])
            {
                if(!ms.empty() && ms.top().second >= burstLen)
                {
                    int count = ms.top().second;
                    
                    while(!ms.empty() && count--)
                        ms.pop();
                        
                    ms.push({s[i], 1});
                }
                
                else
                    ms.push({s[i], 1});
            }
        }

    }
    
    if(!ms.empty() and ms.top().second >= burstLen)
    {
        int count = ms.top().second;
        while(!ms.empty() && count--)
            ms.pop();
    }

    string ans = "";
    while (!ms.empty())
    {
        ans += ms.top().first;
        ms.pop();
    }
    
    reverse(ans.begin(), ans.end());    
    return ans;
}


int main()
{


    int t;
    cin >> t;
    
    while(t--)
    {
        string s;
        int burstLen;
        cin >> s >>burstLen;

        cout << solve(s, burstLen) << "\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Please remove the explanation of the solution from the question, and add it to the answer instead.

Comment: Please remove the `bits/stdc++` header file, as it is not standard, and not something we support.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Is it Right Now ?

Comment: @user4581301 I will try to add a more concise solution to this.

Comment: @Anuragmishra No, it was a month ago.  Although it could be a couple of days from now. Not sure.  What are you talking about?  Stop using the "bits/stdc++" header file.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void solve(){
    System.out.printf("%s\n", solve("abbccccdd", 3));
    System.out.printf("%s\n", solve("abbcccdeaffff", 3));
}

private LinkedList<Node> addToQueue(String S){
    int N = S.length();
    LinkedList<Node> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.addFirst(new Node(S.charAt(0), 1));
    for(int i=1;i<N;i++){

        if(!queue.isEmpty() && queue.getFirst().val==S.charAt(i)) {
            queue.getFirst().count +=1;                                
        } else {
            queue.addFirst(new Node(S.charAt(i), 1));
        }               
    }
    return queue;
}

private String solve(String S, int K){
  
    if(S==null || S.length()==0) return "";
    int N = S.length();
    LinkedList<Node> queue = addToQueue(S);

    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();         
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Node node = queue.removeLast();            
        int count = node.count;
    
        if(count>=K) continue;
        if(isSame(queue, buf)){
            while(isSame(queue, buf)) {
                count += queue.getLast().count;
                queue.removeLast();                 
            }
          
            if(count>=K) buf.deleteCharAt(buf.length()-1);
            else {
                while(count-->0){
                    buf.append(node.val);
                }
            }
        } else {            
            if(count>=K) continue;
            while(count-->0){
                buf.append(node.val);
            }
        } 
    }
    return buf.toString();

}

private boolean isSame(LinkedList<Node> queue, StringBuilder buf){
    if(queue.isEmpty() || buf.length()==0) return false;
    return queue.getLast().val == buf.charAt(buf.length()-1);
}



 class Node {
        char val;
        int count;
        public Node(char c, int count){
            this.val = c;
            this.count = count;
        }
    }
```